# RandomVariate does not fill range of PDF of distribution

Tags: random, probability-or-statistics, distributions

I've declared my own probability distribution as follows

```
dist[a_, b_] := ProbabilityDistribution[Cos[(b x)/2]^2 Sinc[a x]^2, {x, -400, 400}];
```

When I try to create a random variate using this probability distribution I only get data points in a range (-400, -245).

```
data = RandomVariate[dist[200, 500], 10^4];
Histogram[data, 200, "ProbabilityDensity"]
```

[image: Histogram of prob. dist.]

Just to clarify, this isn't an issue with the histogram, when I look at `data` it does only contain numbers in the range seen above.

Comment: Your distribution is not define as it is called in the `RandomVariate` call.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I've edited the question so that it makes sense!

Comment: Also, don't use `D` as your distribution name, that is a built-in symbol.  As a general rule it is always good to start your own function names in lower case to avoid such conflicts.

Comment: Ok, again this is a problem that comes from copy/pasting straight from mathematica notebook.  My distribution is not called `D`, I'm using the curly D that I could not get on this page, I'll edit again to save confusion!

Comment: @Andy It would be useful to have a comment in the docs about what happens if the distribution is not normalized. I didn't expect it would extend/contract the domain in this case, as in `Histogram@RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[x, {x, 0, 1}], 10000]`

Comment: You can gain some insight into what happends by plotting the CDF of your not properly normalised pdf.  The CDF ranges from 0 to the integral of the function, not 1.  This is useful, you can check CDF[dist, xmax ] == 1 to verify a properly normalized distribution. Now the InverseCDF simply inverts the ill formed CDF, but truncates to the range 0-1. If you go through that exercise you can see the weird behavior makes some sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A pdf is only well-defined if it integrates to unity over the domain of support. You have set up the domain of support as (-400, 400). You would have to check what values of $a$ and $b$ (if any) are appropriate for that domain of support. But, more to the point, your domain of support is ill-defined for the parameter values you have provided:

```
f = Cos[(b x)/2]^2 Sinc[a x]^2;

Integrate[ f /. {a -> 200, b -> 500}, {x, -400, 400}] // N
```

> 0.00785395

If you set up the domain of support on the real line `{x,-Infinity, Infinity}`:

```
Integrate[f /. {a -> 200, b -> 500}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> Pi/400

... you just need to multiply your pdf by 400/Pi, and you are all set (given those parameter values for $a$ and $b$).

Comment: Ok, so if I change my probability distribution to `D[a_, b_, A_]:=ProbabilityDistribution[
(Cos[(b x)/2]^2 Sinc[a x]^2)/Integrate[Cos[(b x)/2]^2 Sinc[a x]^2, {x, -A, A}], {x, -A, A}];` should that then work since it guarantees normalisation for any range `A`?

Comment: Wow "The integral of the PDF over the distribution domain needs to be unity:" is burried in the docs under "properties and relations". Poor documentation considering how ill behaved the function is if you dont precisely meet that criteria.

Comment: @george2079 Pardon me, but this shouldn't be in the docs at all, as this is elementary maths. According to the law of total probability, for a "set of pairwise disjoint events whose union is the entire sample space" the sum of all probabilities should be 1. (For continuous distributions, replace sum with integral.)

Comment: It should be clearly documented that it doesn't check for validity.